# Generic Two Dimensional Data Plane with Manipulation Methods For C#

Tags: c#, object-oriented, generics, classes

I know that there is a generic data structure `System.Array` could be used to create customized type array. I want to focus on the two dimensional data structure that something like plane with concatenate methods. The following code is my implementation of a generic two dimensional data structure `Plane<T>`.

Is there any possible improvement of this code?

```cs
public class Plane<T>
{
    private Array PlaneArray;

    public Plane()
    {
        this.PlaneArray = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(T), 1, 1);
    }

    public Plane(Plane<T> ObjectInput)
    {
        this.PlaneArray = ObjectInput.PlaneArray;
    }

    public Plane(uint SizeXInput, uint SizeYInput)
    {
        if (SizeXInput < 0 || SizeYInput < 0)
        {
            this.PlaneArray = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(T), 1, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            this.PlaneArray = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(T), SizeXInput + 1, SizeYInput + 1);
        }
    }

    public Plane<T> ConcatenateHorizontal(Plane<T> PlaneInput)
    {
        if (this.GetSizeY().Equals(PlaneInput.GetSizeY()).Equals(false))
        {
            return default;
        }
        var ReturnObject = new Plane<T>(this.GetSizeX() + PlaneInput.GetSizeX(), this.GetSizeY());
        Parallel.For(0, this.GetSizeY(), (LoopNumberY, stateY) =>
        {
            Parallel.For(0, this.GetSizeX(), (LoopNumberX, stateX) =>
            {
                ReturnObject.SetElement(this.GetElement((uint)LoopNumberX, (uint)LoopNumberY), (uint)LoopNumberX, (uint)LoopNumberY);
            });
        });
        Parallel.For(0, PlaneInput.GetSizeY(), (LoopNumberY, stateY) =>
        {
            Parallel.For(0, PlaneInput.GetSizeX(), (LoopNumberX, stateX) =>
            {
                ReturnObject.SetElement(PlaneInput.GetElement((uint)LoopNumberX, (uint)LoopNumberY), (uint)(LoopNumberX + this.GetSizeX()), (uint)LoopNumberY);
            });
        });

        return ReturnObject;
    }

    public Plane<T> ConcatenateHorizontalInverse(Plane<T> PlaneInput)
    {
        return PlaneInput.ConcatenateHorizontal(this);
    }

    public Plane<T> ConcatenateVertical(Plane<T> PlaneInput)
    {
        if (this.GetSizeX().Equals(PlaneInput.GetSizeX()).Equals(false))
        {
            return new Plane<T>();
        }
        var ReturnObject = new Plane<T>(this.GetSizeX(), this.GetSizeY() + PlaneInput.GetSizeY());
        Parallel.For(0, this.GetSizeY(), (LoopNumberY, stateY) =>
        {
            Parallel.For(0, this.GetSizeX(), (LoopNumberX, stateX) =>
            {
                ReturnObject.SetElement(this.GetElement((uint)LoopNumberX, (uint)LoopNumberY), (uint)LoopNumberX, (uint)LoopNumberY);
            });
        });
        Parallel.For(0, PlaneInput.GetSizeY(), (LoopNumberY, stateY) =>
        {
            Parallel.For(0, PlaneInput.GetSizeX(), (LoopNumberX, stateX) =>
            {
                ReturnObject.SetElement(PlaneInput.GetElement((uint)LoopNumberX, (uint)LoopNumberY), (uint)LoopNumberX, (uint)(LoopNumberY + this.GetSizeY()));
            });
        });
        return ReturnObject;
    }

    public Plane<T> ConcatenateVerticalInverse(Plane<T> BlockStructureInput)
    {
        return BlockStructureInput.ConcatenateVertical(this);
    }

    public T GetElement(uint LocationX, uint LocationY)
    {
        if (LocationX <= this.PlaneArray.GetUpperBound(0) &&
            LocationX >= this.PlaneArray.GetLowerBound(0) &&
            LocationY <= this.PlaneArray.GetUpperBound(1) &&
            LocationY >= this.PlaneArray.GetLowerBound(1))
        {
            return (T)this.PlaneArray.GetValue(LocationX, LocationY);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Index invalid");
        return default(T);
    }

    public uint GetSizeX()
    {
        return (uint)(this.PlaneArray.GetUpperBound(0) - this.PlaneArray.GetLowerBound(0));
    }

    public uint GetSizeY()
    {
        return (uint)(this.PlaneArray.GetUpperBound(1) - this.PlaneArray.GetLowerBound(1));
    }

    public Tuple<bool, Plane<T>> SetElement(T NewElement, uint LocationX, uint LocationY)
    {
        if (LocationX <= this.PlaneArray.GetUpperBound(0) &&
            LocationX >= this.PlaneArray.GetLowerBound(0) &&
            LocationY <= this.PlaneArray.GetUpperBound(1) &&
            LocationY >= this.PlaneArray.GetLowerBound(1))
        {
            this.PlaneArray.SetValue(NewElement, LocationX, LocationY);
            return new Tuple<bool, Plane<T>>(true, this);
        }
        else
        {
            return new Tuple<bool, Plane<T>>(false, this); ;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string ReturnString = "";
        for (uint LoopNumberY = 0; LoopNumberY < this.GetSizeY(); LoopNumberY++)
        {
            for (uint LoopNumberX = 0; LoopNumberX < this.GetSizeX(); LoopNumberX++)
            {
                ReturnString = ReturnString + this.GetElement(LoopNumberX, LoopNumberY).ToString() + "\t");
            }
            ReturnString = ReturnString + System.Environment.NewLine;
        }
        return ReturnString.ToString();
    }
}
```

The usage of this `Plane<T>` class:

```cs
Plane<string> plane = new Plane<string>(5, 5);
for (uint LoopNumberY = 0; LoopNumberY < plane.GetSizeY(); LoopNumberY++)
{
    for (uint LoopNumberX = 0; LoopNumberX < plane.GetSizeX(); LoopNumberX++)
    {
        plane.SetElement("(" + LoopNumberX.ToString() + ", " + LoopNumberY.ToString() + ")", LoopNumberX, LoopNumberY);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(plane.ToString());

var ConcatenateHRetult = plane.ConcatenateHorizontal(plane);
Console.WriteLine(ConcatenateHRetult.ToString());

var ConcatenateVRetult = plane.ConcatenateVertical(plane);
Console.WriteLine(ConcatenateVRetult.ToString());
```

**Oct 16, 2020 Update**

In order to test this Plane class, the customized method `Equals` is needed. Here's my implementation. First, the size comparison is performed, and the next step is checking the content equivalent.

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    var objForTesting = obj as Plane<T>;

    if (this.GetSizeX().Equals(objForTesting.GetSizeX()).Equals(false) ||
        this.GetSizeY().Equals(objForTesting.GetSizeY()).Equals(false)
        )        //    If size is different
    {
        return false;
    }

    //    Content comparison
    for (uint y = 0; y < this.GetSizeY(); y++)
    {
        for (uint x = 0; x < this.GetSizeX(); x++)
        {
            if (this.GetElement(x, y).Equals(objForTesting.GetElement(x, y)).Equals(false))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: If you're concatenating strings and aren't using StringBuilder, you're likely doing it wrong: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/concatenate-multiple-strings

Comment: @BCdotWEB Thank you for the suggestion. The code has been updated.

Comment: @JimmyHu you shouldn't update the code posted in your question (unless it's missing something or there's typo), please revert the changes you've made.

Comment: @cliesens Thank you for the comments. The code has been reverted to the origin version.

Comment: @cliesens as long as no answer is posted, they can update the question.

Comment: See my updated answer regarding C# Indexer to replace `GetElement` and `SetElement`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I would like to re-iterate the points made by @cliesens regarding naming and avoid `uint`.

Keep in mind the most number of elements you may have in an array is `int.MaxValue`.  Theoretically, with your use of `unit`, someone could try to create an array that is 3 billion wide by 3 billion deep, which would throw exceptions.  And your code doesn't handle exceptions very well.

UPDATED: Was it intentional that your constructor accepting a `Plane` copies the source plane by reference?  That would mean that anyone changing something in the copy would also be changing it in the original and vice versa.  I personally would think this should be a cloned copy, instead of a reference copy.

The `ToString()` is a bad idea, not because of the lack of `StringBuilder` but because it could be a very long process.  Let's say I had a plane that is 40K across and 50K tall, for 2 billion elements.  Then I must wait a really long time for `ToString()` to fully render a result.  Since the debugger and other things use `ToString()` to quickly display information, you should have `ToString()` be as fast as it can be.

Thus, I would suggest changing it, and moving your current logic into its own method.  I do find it odd that you choose to display the array by Y and then X (or by Height first then Width) since most people working with a 2D geometric plane tend to think in terms of X first, then Y.  Perhaps you chose to do this so that as it prints down a page it would almost textually mirror the plane rotated around the X-axis.  If so, this would be predicated upon the elements in the X dimension printing neatly across 1 row in the Console window.

I would suggest you may want to have 2 different methods so that one has a choice of the display order.

I would also suggest there could be properties in your class for `Width` and `Height`, which seem more natural to use rather than `GetSizeX()` or `GetSizeY()`.

You employ `System.Array` even though you have a generic class.  All of your calls to `CreateInstance` create a typically 0-indexed array, so calling `GetUpperBound(0) - GetLowerBound(0) + 1` could be replaced with `GetLength(0)`.

Here is my take on a partial design:

```
public class PlaneV2<T>
{
    public int Width { get; } = 0;
    public int Height { get; } = 0;
    private T[,] Grid = null;
    public int Length => Width * Height;

    public PlaneV2() : this(1, 1) { }

    public PlaneV2(int width, int height)
    {
        Width = Math.Max(width, 0);
        Height = Math.Max(height, 0);
        Grid = new T[width, height];
    }

    public PlaneV2(PlaneV2<T> plane) : this(plane?.Grid) { }

    public PlaneV2(T[,] sourceGrid)
    {
        if (sourceGrid == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Width = sourceGrid.GetLength(0);
        Height = sourceGrid.GetLength(1);
        Grid = new T[Width, Height];
        Array.Copy(sourceGrid, Grid, sourceGrid.Length);
    }

    // SNIPPED

    public override string ToString() => $"{nameof(PlaneV2<T>)}<{typeof(T).Name}>[{Width}, {Height}]";

    public string ToDelimitedStringByHeightThenWidth(string separator = "\t")
    {
        StringBuilder lines = new StringBuilder();
        for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
        {
            StringBuilder columns = new StringBuilder();
            string columnDelimiter = "";
            for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
            {
                columns.Append(columnDelimiter + Grid[x, y].ToString());
                if (columnDelimiter == "")
                {
                    columnDelimiter = separator;
                }
            }
            lines.AppendLine(columns.ToString());
        }
        return lines.ToString();
    }

    public string ToDelimitedStringByWidthThenHeight(string separator = "\t")
    {
        StringBuilder lines = new StringBuilder();
        for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
        {
            StringBuilder columns = new StringBuilder();
            string columnDelimiter = "";
            for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
            {
                columns.Append(columnDelimiter + Grid[x, y].ToString());
                if (columnDelimiter == "")
                {
                    columnDelimiter = separator;
                }
            }
            lines.AppendLine(columns.ToString());
        }
        return lines.ToString();
    }

} // class

} // namespace
```

That's about all I can do since I must get back to my daytime job.  To summarize:

1. Consider using properties to your advantage
2. Employ suggested C# naming guidelines
3. Use short, simple naming for loop variables
4. Avoid `unit` for array indexing
5. Have a Width and Height property
6. Consider using a generic array
7. ToString should be short, sweet and FAST
8. Offer a choice to display (X by Y) or (Y by X)

Given that an array can hold int.MaxValue elements, then your biggest **square** plane would be 46_340 X 46_340.  If you wanted to offer HUGE planes, then you would need to change the guts of the class to support an array of arrays.

Other things to consider:

1. Should you implement IEquatable or IComparable?
2. Do you want any constraints, such as struct, on T?

**UPDATE #2 : C# INDEXERS**

I find having GetElement and SetElement methods cumbersome.  I prefer to interact with the object more like an array, and that's where [C# Indexers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/) come in handy.  Here is a way you can get rid of both GetElement and SetElement, while maintaining the same functionality:

```
public T this[int x, int y]
{
    get
    {
        if (x < 0 || x >= Width)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(x));
        }
        if (y < 0 || y >= Height)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(y));
        }
        return Grid[x, y];
    }
    set
    {
        if (x < 0 || x >= Width)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(x));
        }
        if (y < 0 || y >= Height)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(y));
        }
        Grid[x, y] = value;
    }
}
```

And here is a quick example of how to use it:

```
var width = 3;
var height = 5;
var plane = new PlaneV2<int>(width, height);

for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
for (var y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    //NOTICE how I use plane like a 2D array
    plane[x, y] = ((x + 1) * 100) + y;
}

Console.WriteLine("ToString() Example: " + plane.ToString());

Console.WriteLine("\nTAB DELIMITED BY X THEN Y");
Console.WriteLine(plane.ToDelimitedStringByWidthThenHeight());

Console.WriteLine("\nSEMI-COLON DELIMITED BY Y THEN X");
Console.WriteLine(plane.ToDelimitedStringByHeightThenWidth(" ; "));
```

**CONSOLE OUTPUT**

```
ToString() Example: PlaneV2<Int32>[3, 5]

TAB DELIMITED BY X THEN Y
100     101     102     103     104
200     201     202     203     204
300     301     302     303     304

SEMI-COLON DELIMITED BY Y THEN X
100 ; 200 ; 300
101 ; 201 ; 301
102 ; 202 ; 302
103 ; 203 ; 303
104 ; 204 ; 304
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Is it better to use T[,] than `System.Array` object?

Comment: @JimmyHu I personally think its better to use T[,] because the underlying array is now strong-typed, and you may access individual elements without type casting.   For a large plane with millions of elements, it would perform better.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to Code Review!

I don't have much time to write a full review right now, but I'll give you a concise list of things you could do to improve your code (in my opinion).

## Naming

Use `camelCase` instead of `PascalCase` for local variables, class variables & method arguments. In addition to making your code a lot more readable (I don't have to wonder, "is this a variable? a method? a static class?"), it also ensures other people who are familiar with C# will be able to understand and work with your code, as this is the convention followed by most (if not all) C# programmers.

I'm also not a very big fan of super long names for the `for` loop iterating variable. I generally stick to `i`, `j` and sometimes `k`, or use other descriptive names when I'm not simply iterating over indices. But to me, `LoopNumberX` is really way too long and actually makes the code harder to read. What does `LoopNumberX` even mean? Again, this is a personal preference, but I don't think there's many people who would argue `LoopNumberX` is a good name. If you know what a `for` loop is, then whenever you see `i` or `j`, you'll know exactly what is going on.

## Properties

You could make your code even more maintainable & easy to understand by using properties. You should use `PascalCase` when naming properties. Here are some examples of using properties in various ways:

```
private int x;

public int X
{
    public get 
    {
        return x;
    }

    public set 
    {
        x = value;
    }
}
```

Which you can shorten to :

```
private int x;

public int X
{
    public get => x;

    public set => x = value;
}
```

As there is only a single statement is the getter/setter. You can go even further and remove the private field entirely like this :

```
public int X { get; private set; }
```

This is called an auto-property. This example also shows how you can give the property, its setter and getter different access modifiers. You can also add logic inside the getter/setter like this :

```
private int x;

public int X
{
    public get { return x; }

    public set 
    {
        if (x < 0) {
            throw new Exception("X should be larger than 0!");
        }

        x = value;
    }
}
```

Properties are great, use them whenever you can (though they shouldn't replace all your methods of course, only when appropriate)!

## `uint`

I'd recommend against using `uint` everywhere as you do, even though it may seem like a good idea. If you'd like more information on this subject, I recommend taking a quick look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013116/should-i-use-uint-in-c-sharp-for-values-that-cant-be-negative.

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Index invalid");
    return default(T);
```

is dangerous. Having out-of-bounds indices is dangerous enough that you should probably just raise an exception here, rather than returning a default that will probably be wrong from the perspective of the caller. If this is a feature that you're really going to use, wrap it in a second function (`TryGetElement`) that follows the same pattern as other methods in C#: have an output parameter that might be set, and return a boolean that is only true if the call succeeded.