# SubImage function implementation in C

Tags: c, reinventing-the-wheel, error-handling, image, memory-management

This is a follow-up question for [Two dimensional gaussian image generator in C](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/263024/231235), [Two dimensional bicubic interpolation implementation in C](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/263183/231235) and [A SubPlane Method for Generic Two Dimensional Data Plane in C#](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251570/231235). Besides gaussian image generating and bicubic interpolation, I am attempting to make a C version subimage function in this post so that the [ROI (Region of interest)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Region_of_interest) of an image can be extracted.

The output subimage example:

[image: SubImage]

**The experimental implementation**

- `SubMonoImage` function implementation: subimage extracting operation for `MONOIMAGE` structure.

  ```
  MONOIMAGE SubMonoImage(const MONOIMAGE image, unsigned int locationx, unsigned int locationy, unsigned int sizex, unsigned int sizey)
  {
      MONOIMAGE output = CreateMonoImage(sizex, sizey);
      for (size_t y = 0; y < sizey; y++)
      {
          for (size_t x = 0; x < sizex; x++)
          {
              if ((locationy + y) < image.XSIZE &&
                  (locationx + x) < image.YSIZE)          //  valid location
              {
                  output.IMAGE_DATA[GetMonoImageIndex(x, y, output)] = 
                      image.IMAGE_DATA[GetMonoImageIndex((locationx + x), (locationy + y), image)];
              }
          }
      }
      return output;
  }
  ```
- `SubRGBImage` function implementation: subimage extracting operation for `RGBIMAGE` structure.

  ```
  RGBIMAGE SubRGBImage(const RGBIMAGE image, unsigned int locationx, unsigned int locationy, unsigned int sizex, unsigned int sizey)
  {
      MONOIMAGE R = SubMonoImage(GetPlaneR(image), locationx, locationy, sizex, sizey);
      MONOIMAGE G = SubMonoImage(GetPlaneG(image), locationx, locationy, sizex, sizey);
      MONOIMAGE B = SubMonoImage(GetPlaneB(image), locationx, locationy, sizex, sizey);
      RGBIMAGE output = CreateRGBImageFromMonoImages(sizex, sizey, R, G, B);
      DeleteMonoImage(R);
      DeleteMonoImage(G);
      DeleteMonoImage(B);
      return output;
  }
  ```
- `basic_functions.h`: Contains several basic function declarations

  ```
  /* Develop by Jimmy Hu */

  #ifndef BASIC_FUNCTIONS_H
  #define BASIC_FUNCTIONS_H

  #include "base.h"
  #include "imageio.h"

  MONOIMAGE CreateMonoImage(const unsigned int, const unsigned int);

  void DeleteMonoImage(MONOIMAGE);

  MONOIMAGE GetPlaneR(const RGBIMAGE);

  MONOIMAGE GetPlaneG(const RGBIMAGE);

  MONOIMAGE GetPlaneB(const RGBIMAGE);

  RGBIMAGE CreateRGBImage(const unsigned int, const unsigned int);

  RGBIMAGE CreateRGBImageFromMonoImages(const unsigned int, const unsigned int, MONOIMAGE, MONOIMAGE, MONOIMAGE);

  void DeleteRGBImage(RGBIMAGE);

  size_t GetMonoImageIndex(const size_t, const size_t, const MONOIMAGE);

  size_t GetRGBImageIndex(const size_t, const size_t, const RGBIMAGE);

  size_t clip(const size_t, const size_t, const size_t);

  float clip_float(const float, const float, const float);

  #endif
  ```
- `basic_functions.c`: Contains several basic function definitions

  ```
  /* Develop by Jimmy Hu */

  #include "basic_functions.h"

  MONOIMAGE CreateMonoImage(const unsigned int sizex, const unsigned int sizey)
  {
      MONOIMAGE output;
      output.XSIZE = sizex;
      output.YSIZE = sizey;
      output.IMAGE_DATA = malloc(sizeof *output.IMAGE_DATA * sizex * sizey);
      if(output.IMAGE_DATA == NULL)
      {    
          printf(stderr, "Memory allocation error!");
          return output;
      }
      return output;
  }

  void DeleteMonoImage(MONOIMAGE image)
  {
      free(image.IMAGE_DATA);
      return;
  }

  MONOIMAGE GetPlaneR(const RGBIMAGE image)
  {
      MONOIMAGE output = CreateMonoImage(image.XSIZE, image.YSIZE);
      for (size_t y = 0; y < image.YSIZE; y++)
      {
          for (size_t x = 0; x < image.XSIZE; x++)
          {
              output.IMAGE_DATA[GetMonoImageIndex(x, y, output)] = 
                  image.IMAGE_DATA[GetRGBImageIndex(x, y, image)].channels[0];
          }
      }
      return output;
  }

  MONOIMAGE GetPlaneG(const RGBIMAGE image)
  {
      MONOIMAGE output = CreateMonoImage(image.XSIZE, image.YSIZE);
      for (size_t y = 0; y < image.YSIZE; y++)
      {
          for (size_t x = 0; x < image.XSIZE; x++)
          {
              output.IMAGE_DATA[GetMonoImageIndex(x, y, output)] = 
                  image.IMAGE_DATA[GetRGBImageIndex(x, y, image)].channels[1];
          }
      }
      return output;
  }

  MONOIMAGE GetPlaneB(const RGBIMAGE image)
  {
      MONOIMAGE output = CreateMonoImage(image.XSIZE, image.YSIZE);
      for (size_t y = 0; y < image.YSIZE; y++)
      {
          for (size_t x = 0; x < image.XSIZE; x++)
          {
              output.IMAGE_DATA[GetMonoImageIndex(x, y, output)] = 
                  image.IMAGE_DATA[GetRGBImageIndex(x, y, image)].channels[2];
          }
      }
      return output;
  }

  RGBIMAGE CreateRGBImage(const unsigned int sizex, const unsigned int sizey)
  {
      RGBIMAGE output;
      output.XSIZE = sizex;
      output.YSIZE = sizey;
      output.IMAGE_DATA = malloc(sizeof *output.IMAGE_DATA * sizex * sizey);
      if(output.IMAGE_DATA == NULL)
      {    
          printf(stderr, "Memory allocation error!");
          return output;
      }
      return output;
  }

  RGBIMAGE CreateRGBImageFromMonoImages(const unsigned int sizex, const unsigned int sizey, MONOIMAGE R, MONOIMAGE G, MONOIMAGE B)
  {
      RGBIMAGE output;
      output.XSIZE = sizex;
      output.YSIZE = sizey;
      output.IMAGE_DATA = malloc(sizeof *output.IMAGE_DATA * sizex * sizey);
      if (output.IMAGE_DATA == NULL)
      {    
          printf(stderr, "Memory allocation error!");
          return output;
      }
      if ((R.XSIZE != G.XSIZE) ||
          (G.XSIZE != B.XSIZE) ||
          (R.XSIZE != B.XSIZE) ||
          (R.YSIZE != G.YSIZE) ||
          (G.YSIZE != B.YSIZE) ||
          (R.YSIZE != B.YSIZE))
      {
          printf(stderr, "Input size inequal!");
          return output;
      }
      for (size_t y = 0; y < R.YSIZE; y++)
      {
          for (size_t x = 0; x < R.XSIZE; x++)
          {
              output.IMAGE_DATA[GetRGBImageIndex(x, y, output)].channels[0] = R.IMAGE_DATA[GetMonoImageIndex(x, y, R)];
              output.IMAGE_DATA[GetRGBImageIndex(x, y, output)].channels[1] = G.IMAGE_DATA[GetMonoImageIndex(x, y, G)];
              output.IMAGE_DATA[GetRGBImageIndex(x, y, output)].channels[2] = B.IMAGE_DATA[GetMonoImageIndex(x, y, B)];
          }
      }
      return output;
  }

  void DeleteRGBImage(RGBIMAGE image)
  {
      free(image.IMAGE_DATA);
      return;
  }

  size_t GetMonoImageIndex(const size_t x, const size_t y, const MONOIMAGE image)
  {
      return y * image.XSIZE + x;
  }

  size_t GetRGBImageIndex(const size_t x, const size_t y, const RGBIMAGE image)
  {
      return y * image.XSIZE + x;
  }

  size_t clip(const size_t input, const size_t lowerbound, const size_t upperbound)
  {
      if (input < lowerbound)
      {
          return lowerbound;
      }
      if (input > upperbound)
      {
          return upperbound;
      }
      return input;
  }

  float clip_float(const float input, const float lowerbound, const float upperbound)
  {
      if (input < lowerbound)
      {
          return lowerbound;
      }
      if (input > upperbound)
      {
          return upperbound;
      }
      return input;
  }
  ```
- `base.h`: Contains the basic type implementation

  ```
  /* Develop by Jimmy Hu */

  #ifndef BASE_H
  #define BASE_H

  #include <math.h>
  #include <stdbool.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <unistd.h>

  #define MAX_PATH 256
  #define FILE_ROOT_PATH "./"

  #define True true
  #define False false

  typedef struct RGB
  {
      unsigned char channels[3];
  } RGB;

  typedef struct HSV
  {
      long double channels[3];    //  Range: 0 <= H < 360, 0 <= S <= 1, 0 <= V <= 255
  }HSV;

  typedef struct BMPIMAGE
  {
      char FILENAME[MAX_PATH];

      unsigned int XSIZE;
      unsigned int YSIZE;
      unsigned char FILLINGBYTE;
      unsigned char *IMAGE_DATA;
  } BMPIMAGE;

  typedef struct RGBIMAGE
  {
      unsigned int XSIZE;
      unsigned int YSIZE;
      RGB *IMAGE_DATA;
  } RGBIMAGE;

  typedef struct HSVIMAGE
  {
      unsigned int XSIZE;
      unsigned int YSIZE;
      HSV *IMAGE_DATA;
  } HSVIMAGE;

  typedef struct MONOIMAGE
  {
      unsigned int XSIZE;
      unsigned int YSIZE;
      unsigned char *IMAGE_DATA;
  } MONOIMAGE;

  typedef struct DOUBLEIMAGE
  {
      unsigned int XSIZE;
      unsigned int YSIZE;
      double *IMAGE_DATA;
  };

  #endif
  ```

**The full testing code**

```
/* Develop by Jimmy Hu */

#include "base.h"
#include "basic_functions.h"
#include "imageio.h"

MONOIMAGE BicubicInterpolationMonoImage(MONOIMAGE image, const int, const int);

RGBIMAGE BicubicInterpolationRGBImage(RGBIMAGE image, const int, const int);

unsigned char BicubicPolate(const unsigned char*, const float, const float);

float CubicPolate(const float, const float, const float, const float, const float);

/*  Subimage extracting operation for MONOIMAGE structure
*/
MONOIMAGE SubMonoImage(const MONOIMAGE, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int);

/*  Subimage extracting operation for RGBIMAGE structure
*/
RGBIMAGE SubRGBImage(const RGBIMAGE, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char *FilenameString;
    FilenameString = malloc( sizeof *FilenameString * MAX_PATH);
    
    printf("BMP image input file name:(ex:test): ");
    scanf("%s", FilenameString);
    BMPIMAGE BMPImage1 = bmp_file_read(FilenameString, false);
    RGBIMAGE RGBImage1;
    RGBImage1.XSIZE = BMPImage1.XSIZE;
    RGBImage1.YSIZE = BMPImage1.YSIZE;
    RGBImage1.IMAGE_DATA = raw_image_to_array(BMPImage1.XSIZE, BMPImage1.YSIZE, BMPImage1.IMAGE_DATA);

    RGBIMAGE RGBImage2 = SubRGBImage(RGBImage1, 150, 100, 250, 300);
    RGBIMAGE RGBImage3 = BicubicInterpolationRGBImage(RGBImage2, RGBImage2.XSIZE * 2, RGBImage2.YSIZE * 2);
    
    printf("file name for saving:(ex:test): ");
    scanf("%s", FilenameString);
    bmp_write(FilenameString, RGBImage3.XSIZE, RGBImage3.YSIZE, array_to_raw_image(RGBImage3.XSIZE, RGBImage3.YSIZE, RGBImage3.IMAGE_DATA));

    free(FilenameString);
    DeleteRGBImage(RGBImage1);
    DeleteRGBImage(RGBImage2);
    DeleteRGBImage(RGBImage3);
    return 0;
}

MONOIMAGE BicubicInterpolationMonoImage(MONOIMAGE image, const int newSizeX, const int newSizeY)
{
    MONOIMAGE output = CreateMonoImage(newSizeX, newSizeY);
    int originSizeX = image.XSIZE;
    int originSizeY = image.YSIZE;
    if (output.IMAGE_DATA == NULL)
    {
        printf(stderr, "Memory allocation error!");
        return output;
    }
    
    float ratiox = (float)originSizeX / (float)newSizeX;
    float ratioy = (float)originSizeY / (float)newSizeY;
    
    for (size_t y = 0; y < newSizeY; y++)
    {
        for (size_t x = 0; x < newSizeX; x++)
        {
            float xMappingToOrigin = (float)x * ratiox;
            float yMappingToOrigin = (float)y * ratioy;
            float xMappingToOriginFloor = floor(xMappingToOrigin);
            float yMappingToOriginFloor = floor(yMappingToOrigin);
            float xMappingToOriginFrac = xMappingToOrigin - xMappingToOriginFloor;
            float yMappingToOriginFrac = yMappingToOrigin - yMappingToOriginFloor;
            
            unsigned char ndata[4 * 4];
            for (int ndatay = -1; ndatay <= 2; ndatay++)
            {
                for (int ndatax = -1; ndatax <= 2; ndatax++)
                {
                    ndata[(ndatay + 1) * 4 + (ndatax + 1)] = image.IMAGE_DATA[
                        clip(yMappingToOriginFloor + ndatay, 0, originSizeY - 1) * originSizeX + 
                        clip(xMappingToOriginFloor + ndatax, 0, originSizeX - 1)
                        ];
                }
            }

            output.IMAGE_DATA[ y * newSizeX + x ] = BicubicPolate(ndata, xMappingToOriginFrac, yMappingToOriginFrac);
        }
    }
    return output;
}

RGBIMAGE BicubicInterpolationRGBImage(RGBIMAGE image, const int newSizeX, const int newSizeY)
{
    MONOIMAGE R = BicubicInterpolationMonoImage(GetPlaneR(image), newSizeX, newSizeY);
    MONOIMAGE G = BicubicInterpolationMonoImage(GetPlaneG(image), newSizeX, newSizeY);
    MONOIMAGE B = BicubicInterpolationMonoImage(GetPlaneB(image), newSizeX, newSizeY);
    RGBIMAGE output = CreateRGBImageFromMonoImages(newSizeX, newSizeY, R, G, B);
    DeleteMonoImage(R);
    DeleteMonoImage(G);
    DeleteMonoImage(B);
    return output;
}

unsigned char BicubicPolate(const unsigned char* const ndata, const float fracx, const float fracy)
{
    float x1 = CubicPolate( ndata[0], ndata[1], ndata[2], ndata[3], fracx );
    float x2 = CubicPolate( ndata[4], ndata[5], ndata[6], ndata[7], fracx );
    float x3 = CubicPolate( ndata[8], ndata[9], ndata[10], ndata[11], fracx );
    float x4 = CubicPolate( ndata[12], ndata[13], ndata[14], ndata[15], fracx );

    float output = clip_float(CubicPolate( x1, x2, x3, x4, fracy ), 0.0, 255.0);
    return (unsigned char)output;
}

float CubicPolate(const float v0, const float v1, const float v2, const float v3, const float fracy)
{
    float A = (v3-v2)-(v0-v1);
    float B = (v0-v1)-A;
    float C = v2-v0;
    float D = v1;
    return D + fracy * (C + fracy * (B + fracy * A));
}

MONOIMAGE SubMonoImage(const MONOIMAGE image, unsigned int locationx, unsigned int locationy, unsigned int sizex, unsigned int sizey)
{
    MONOIMAGE output = CreateMonoImage(sizex, sizey);
    for (size_t y = 0; y < sizey; y++)
    {
        for (size_t x = 0; x < sizex; x++)
        {
            if ((locationy + y) < image.XSIZE &&
                (locationx + x) < image.YSIZE)          //  valid location
            {
                output.IMAGE_DATA[GetMonoImageIndex(x, y, output)] = 
                    image.IMAGE_DATA[GetMonoImageIndex((locationx + x), (locationy + y), image)];
            }
        }
    }
    return output;
}

RGBIMAGE SubRGBImage(const RGBIMAGE image, unsigned int locationx, unsigned int locationy, unsigned int sizex, unsigned int sizey)
{
    MONOIMAGE R = SubMonoImage(GetPlaneR(image), locationx, locationy, sizex, sizey);
    MONOIMAGE G = SubMonoImage(GetPlaneG(image), locationx, locationy, sizex, sizey);
    MONOIMAGE B = SubMonoImage(GetPlaneB(image), locationx, locationy, sizex, sizey);
    RGBIMAGE output = CreateRGBImageFromMonoImages(sizex, sizey, R, G, B);
    DeleteMonoImage(R);
    DeleteMonoImage(G);
    DeleteMonoImage(B);
    return output;
}
```

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [Two dimensional gaussian image generator in C](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/263024/231235),

  [Two dimensional bicubic interpolation implementation in C](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/263183/231235) and

  [A SubPlane Method for Generic Two Dimensional Data Plane in C#](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/251570/231235).
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  I am attempting to make a C version subimage function in this post.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  If there is any possible improvement, please let me know.

**Reference**

- [The Lenna Story](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Echuck/lennapg/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are image representations that lend themselves much better to passing around views of rectangular crops:

```
struct Image {
    void *pixels;
    enum format pixel_format;
    size_t width;
    size_t height;
    size_t stride;
}
```

With `pixels` pointing to the top-left position in the source image, and `stride` copied from the source's stride, then we don't need to copy the data.  If we do want to copy, then that can be a separate function.  That helps separate our concerns.

Unrelated, please don't use ALL_CAPS names for C identifiers.  It's usual to use capitals for preprocessor macros; these need to be distinguished because they are text substitutions rather than names, and are not confined to a particular scope.  When ordinary names are all-caps, it makes it harder to pick out the macros and give them the caution they require.